# Fortran compiler .exe

Tags: executable, fortran

I want to extract Fortran source code from an .exe file. How do I do this?
For ex. I write a program and i just have a exe file of it this porgram calculate amount of velocity 
In other program i wanna use velocity that calculated in exe file 
How can I open exe file in the main body and read velocity from it?

Comment: Are you asking about a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler)? What "data" do you hope to recover?

Comment: Please improve your question by providing more detail.

Comment: This is not the correct forum for asking questions about a **de-compiler** for Fortran. *This is too specialised a subject, and not particularly platform specific.*

Comment: I think he doesn't even want a decompiler or the code at all. Sounds to me like he wants to call the first binary to do it's calculation and use the output. If he want's to do that from Fortran, that's a question for StackOverflow. With the shell it would simply be `./exe1 params | exe2`, if exe1 writes to stdout and exe2 reads from it

Answer (score 1):

Executables don't directly contain the code used to produce them.

However, they can be decompiled, producing *equivalent* code in a high-level programming language such as Fortran. Unfortunately, this won't usually be very legible. Expect random variable names and terrible spaghetti code.

Searching the web for "Fortran compiler" finds a few applications, however I haven't tested any of those.